# cals table nobreak

Tags: tables, cals

How to keep together the same numbers? The `\nobreak` does not work. Sorry, for my poor english :)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,landscape]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=20mm, bottom=20mm, left=20mm, right=20mm}
\geometry{includemp=false}
\geometry{includehead=true,includefoot=true}
\geometry{layouthoffset=0mm, layoutvoffset=0mm}
\geometry{headsep=10pt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cals}

\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\begin{calstable}
\colwidths{
{100pt}
{100pt}
{100pt}
}
\thead{
\brow
\alignC
\cell{head1}
\nullcell{ltb}
\nullcell{tbr}
\spancontent{head2}
\erow
}
\tfoot{
\hrule width 300pt height 0.4pt depth 0pt\relax
}

\brow
\cell{1}
\cell{111}
\cell{111}
\erow

\brow
\cell{2}
\cell{222}
\cell{222}
\erow

\brow
\cell{}
\cell{222}
\cell{222}
\erow

\brow
\cell{3}
\cell{333}
\cell{333}
\erow

\brow
\cell{}
\cell{333}
\cell{333}
\erow

\brow
\cell{}
\cell{333}
\cell{333}
\erow

\brow
\cell{4}
\cell{444}
\cell{444}
\erow

\brow
\cell{}
\cell{444}
\cell{444}
\erow

\brow
\cell{}
\cell{444}
\cell{444}
\erow

\brow
\cell{}
\cell{444}
\cell{444}
\erow

\brow
\cell{5}
\cell{555}
\cell{555}
\erow

%\nobreak

\brow
\cell{}
\cell{555}
\cell{555}
\erow

\brow
\cell{}
\cell{555}
\cell{555}
\erow

\brow
\cell{}
\cell{555}
\cell{555}
\erow

\brow
\cell{}
\cell{555}
\cell{555}
\erow

\brow
\cell{6}
\cell{666}
\cell{666}
\erow

\end{calstable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to insert `\nobreak`, I'd recommend to join cells vertically. Then you automatically get the rows together.

```
\brow \nullcell{tlr}\cell{555}\cell{555} \erow
\brow \nullcell{lr}\cell{555}\cell{555} \erow
\brow \nullcell{lr}\cell{555}\cell{555} \erow
\brow \nullcell{lr}\cell{555}\cell{555} \erow
\brow \nullcell{blr}\spancontent{5}\cell{555}\cell{555} \erow
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this solution is perfect for me!

But I have a question: is it possible to have lines in the spancontent field, too? Or is there any other solution for not breaking the same numbers?

Comment: 1) Spancontent is always line-free.
2) caltable uses its own page breaking. If you want all the "5"-rows together, instead of "nobreak" between, insert "break" before the whole group: `\tbreak{\break}`
3) You can disable breaking between some rows, but it's a bit complicated. I think the method (2) is much better.

Answer (score 0):

You may set a manual table break (`\tbreak{<code>}`) between the rows where you want the page breaks:

```
\brow
\cell{}
\cell{444}
\cell{444}
\erow

\tbreak{\vfill\break} % < - manual break

\brow
\cell{5}
\cell{555}
\cell{555}
\erow
```

See Oleg Parashchenko’s article in [TUGboat, Volume 32 (2011) p. 193](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-2/tb101parashchenko.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, I know manual break (\tbreak), but I do not want, I need "\nobreak".